# How to define several ScenarioLibraries in Xebium

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, fitnesse

Is there any way to define multiple ScenarioLibraries in Xebium (http://xebia.github.io/Xebium/) and use a different subset of them in each test suite? For example FirstScenarioLibrary and SecondScenarioLibrary and include FirstScenarioLibrary in FirstTestSuite and SecondScenarioLibrary in SecondTestSuite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScenarioLibrary is not an special mechansim. It is just a default page that is automatically included in each test suite. So you can create your own static pages containing scenarios and import them in any test suite of your own interest by using `!include` directive. Have a look at this link: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/xebium/MvlhK8u_AR0/vqPf8kSodfwJ